# Play framework scala query binding for java class

Tags: java, scala, playframework, enums

I've got a java enum class

```
public enum MahEnum {
  YUP, VALUES
}
```

and a scala query binding so that I can use that enum in routes

```
object MahBindings {
  implicit def enumBinding = new QueryStringBindable[MahEnum] { 
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, MahEnum]] = ???
    def unbind(key: String, value: Status): String = ???
  }
}
```

How do I get play to recognize the bindings and apply them? If the bound class were in scala I could put the object in the scope of the class, but I've got a java enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `QueryStringBindable` is already defined, you can import the implicits into the routes file with an sbt key. For Play 2.5.x and 2.4.x:

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys

RoutesKeys.routesImport += "MahBindings._"
```

Play 2.3.x and prior:

```
PlayKeys.routesImport += "MahBindings._"
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I couldn't find that in the documentation anywhere. Also a clarification for anyone who reads this in the future: the import and `RoutesKeys` setting go in `build.sbt`, not the `routes` file.